# how to skip null values in odata response?

Tags: null, odata, skip

I have an odata web service that is returning some null values. I would like to skip these null values. 
I tried to use the Ne(Not equal) operator to filter the data with null values:

```
analyticView.xsodata/analyticView?$select=QUANTITY_SOLD,SALE_PRICE&$filter=SALE_PRICE+Ne+null)&$format=json
```

and I am getting the following error message:

```
"Illegal operation 'Ne' at position 11."
```

I tried also to combine the Not operator with the eq operator in this way:

```
analyticView.xsodata/analyticView?$select=QUANTITY_SOLD,SALE_PRICE&$filter=not(SALE_PRICE+eq+null)&$format=json
```

I keep getting an error message saying:

```
value: "No property 'null' exists in type ...
```

I am using SAP HANA analytic view as a data source, but I thing the issue is not vendor dependent. 
so, what to do to skip the null values?

Comment: how is `SALE_PRICE` defined in the class?

Comment: if understand your question, here is how the SALE_PRICE is defined within the metadata of the odata provider <Property Name="SALE_PRICE" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="34"/>

Comment: I guess I'm trying to understand if SALE_PRICE is nullable and if this might be the issue because the syntax looks correct and works for me here through the OData found in the `System.Web.Http.OData` namespace.

Comment: there is a stray bracket in the first example `$filter=SALE_PRICE+Ne+null)&` if that helps?

Comment: yet another question, to have the null keyword recognized and not generating the error in the second example should my attribute by deliberately set with nullable=true?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The above solutions should work fine, baring in mind that the operators are case sensitive as pointed out by Tne. 
So in general to filter null values you can use:

- $filter=(SALE_PRICE+ne+null)
- or $filter=not(SALE_PRICE+eq+null)

However in the particular case of SAP HANA analytic views the null value is not supported, as a workaround the filters can be defined on the table column at the modeling level of the analytic view. The solution is explained [here](http://intelligea.wordpress.com/2013/10/15/how-to-skip-null-values-in-odata-response/).

Answer (score 6):

Note that the operators are case-sensitive.  (Use `ne` instead of `Ne`.)

The spec does mention that *"ISNULL or COALESCE operators are not defined. Instead, there is a null literal which can be used in comparisons"* (v3.0, URL Conventions, section 5.1.2.4), which means that it should work.

Indeed, I tried `Property ne null` without any issue.  What's weird is that your attempt with `not`, although not useful, should have worked.  Maybe look at replacing `+` characters with spaces (possibly encoded), maybe the server is confused.